# Print full path to home directory

Tags: partition

`echo $HOME` will just print  `/home/user`.  But in my system, `/home` is not mounted under `/` and is neither is its own partition.

```
# shared linux data partition, `/home` is here
UUID=a89334f7-59b7-4d04-b89b-a5a30c379644  /mnt/linux_data  ext4  defaults  1 2
```

The home directory is mounted using a bind mount,

```
# bind mount /home to directory to a directory on /linux_data
/mnt/linux_data/01_centos  /home   none  bind   0 0
```

Clicking on the home directory icon in Caja, the location bar indicates  `/home/user`. But this directory should actually be `/mnt/linux_data/01_centos/user` which does exist in that location. I can navigate to `/mnt/linux_data/01_centos/user` by going through  `/root` icon in Caja but I would like some means to print the full path to what the OS believes to be  `/home`.

Comment: `sudo lsblk;df;cat /etc/mtab;mount`. Read `man lsblk df mtab mount`.

Comment: if you have it bind mounted to `/home`, then for all intents and purposes, it _is_ mounted there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$HOME` is set to what is in `/etc/passwd` for the user. To see for yourself, create a directory called `/opt/username` for a user, make them the owner, and then use `vipw` to change their home to `/opt/username` in `/etc/passwd`. Log in as the user and use `pwd` and you'll see that they are in `/opt/username` and that `$HOME` expands to `/opt/username`.

If you use the command `grep username /etc/passwd` or `getent passwd username`, then you'll see that the home is set to `/home/username` and not `/mnt/linux_data/01_centos/user`. As far as the OS is concerned, the home is indeed `/home/username` regardless of whether another filesystem is mounted there. Your system is functioning exactly as it should.

To clarify for LDAP, if there are users who authenticate via LDAP, then their home directories will be designated in the LDAP server which is usually Active Directory. You'll still be able to see it with `getent passwd` and if it's changed there, the `$HOME` variable will reflect this.

Comment: and even if the directory doesn't exist, `$HOME` would still point to what ever the directory in the user database was...